# How to call useEffect after page reload ? After reloading my state (data) is show an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my code after reloading the page  my data(useState) doesn't set the store data which is coming from redux reducer .

```
const DataShow= ({getDatashow}) => {
  const newState = useSelector((state) => state?.User);
  console.log(newState)
  const [data, setData] = useState(newState);
  useEffect(() => {
    getDatashow()
  }, []);


  return (
<></>
)
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getDatashow: ()=> dispatch(getDatashow())
  };
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DataShow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dependancy array to call useEffect

But you redux state data will automatically update. so you no need to set data into state.

You can use it directly to your flat list and any where else

```
newState && newState.map(...rest)
```

Comment: I used this but it doesn't work it also creating a of problem of rendering state as multiple times.

Comment: Than you can directly use your newState data, it will behave same as the state and even it will update automatically